# create dynamic interface in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Based on some user input i want to create the following interface (styles are missing).

```
    Button btn = new Button();
    Slider sld = new Slider();
    ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox();
    btn.setText("Click me");
    sld.autosize();
    cb.autosize();      

    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn,sld,cb);
```

So if the user writes the number 3 i want to create these three components times the number 3 in that specific order. Also every ChoiceBox affects the range of the slider. So i want to create multiple components and i also want to know that when i click on an option in the choicebox it will affect the specific slider above it. I've searched for similar posts but i haven't found anything similar to my question. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please show what you tried  ([MCVE])

Comment: Use a loop and a `onAction` event handler for the `ChoiceBox`???